# What is the best way to encrypt all data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, security

I need some way to encrypt all customer data into mysql. If my server is hacked they will never decrypt data.

Comment: If your server is hacked, the attacker can also find the decryption key.  Security is not that easy.

Comment: Yes, but I thinking some way that don't need save key in the server

Comment: Then how will you decrypt it?  And how would the server run queries?

Comment: If the data is relatively small there is the option of procuring an external device (HSM or similar) that contains the key and also performs the encryption/decryption thus the key is never available and then only that device must be administrated securely. It is also possible to have dual-custody so that no one individual can obtain access to the device. Prices starting at around $500 ranging up to $100K, a lot depends on the required thru-put: entry size * entries/minute.

Comment: Also, your MySQL server should not be accessible from the Internet, neither should it be the same machine as your application is running on.  If something is going to be hacked, it should not be your database.

Comment: Hacking a database is not like eating piece of cake. If someone is really capable to hack all the way down to server and database then there is nothing you can do to prevent data hacking. Ask pentagon about Chinese hackers

Answer (score 1):

More detail would make it easier to help. Are you accessing the data regularly? If which server is hacked? The database? Or the application server? What data are you trying to encrypt?

In general you have a few options. You can encrypt at the data storage level with something like [dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt). Or you can encrypt at the MySQL level by using the [the internal encryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html). Either way your primary issue is that of key management.

You can go for a robust key management option such as [HashiCorp's Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/). Or you can do something as simple as storing the decryption key on your application server. That way your application can decrypt any necessary data, but in order for an attacker to access decrypted data they would have to gain access to both your database and application servers. Not a great solution, but better than nothing.

This answer also has some great advice: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12334

Comment: Data of customer from financial business. I will investigate your options thanks buddy